# How to disable/enable a button when UITextfield data isEmpty or filled?

Tags: ios, swift

[image: Output Console]

Here is my function. As you can see above, I am able to receive a message in the console when the text field is empty (or nil), and the button is disabled. However, when data is entered into my text field, I am not getting a response. Much appreciation if someone can help me with a solution for this or an analogous one.

```
func logicDataCheck() {
    let textfield: Array<Bool?> = [lastNameTextField.text?.isEmpty, phoneNumberTextField.text?.isEmpty, firstNameTextField.text?.isEmpty]

    if (textfield[0]! || textfield [1]! || textfield [2]!)
    {
        print("Textfield is empty")
        continue_Button.isEnabled = false
        continue_Button.alpha = 0.5
    }
    else 
    {
        if (textfield[0]! || textfield [1]! || textfield [2]!) {
            print("Textfield is full")
            continue_Button.isEnabled = true
            continue_Button.alpha = 1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `viewDidLoad`, you could add the following lines:

```
configureTextFields()
// you'll need to call updateTextField() when the view loads the first time.
// After the configureTextFields() adds targets, it'll get called when editing changes
updateTextField()
```

Also, add these methods:

```
func configureTextFields() {
    // create an array of textfields
    let textFieldArray = [firstNameTextField, lastNameTextField, phoneNumberTextField]

    // configure them...
    for textField in textFieldArray {
        // make sure you set the delegate to be self
        textField?.delegate = self
        // add a target to them
        textField?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.updateTextField), for: .editingChanged)
    }
}

// this is the target that gets called when editing changes
func updateTextField() {
    // create an array of textFields
    let textFields = [firstNameTextField, lastNameTextField, phoneNumberTextField]
    // create a bool to test if a textField is blank in the textFields array
    let oneOfTheTextFieldsIsBlank = textFields.contains(where: {($0?.text ?? "").isEmpty})
    if oneOfTheTextFieldsIsBlank {
        continueButton.isEnabled = false
        continueButton.alpha = 0.5
    } else {
        continueButton.isEnabled = true
        continueButton.alpha = 1.0
    }
}
```

You need to make your ViewController adopt the UITextFieldDelegate protocol. You can do this like so:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
// the code inside your view controller
}
```

Here is a link to a [demo I created on GitHub](https://github.com/AdrianBinDC/EnableTextFieldDemo)

Comment: note that `emptyCheck` is actually an array of optional strings and you should disable the button when one of them is `nil`, too. Therefore the check should be `{$0 != false}`. Also, the code would be simpler, if you defined an array of text fields, e.g. `let textFields: [UITextField] = [firstNameTextField, ...]` and then `let emptyCheck = textFields.contains(where: {($0.text ?? "").isEmpty})`.

Comment: @Sulthan Awesome feedback. I updated based on your input.

Comment: @KyleC.Beachem Answer updated. Please click the checkmark to accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: Just did, Thanks @Adrian

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
func logicDataCheck() {
    let textfield: Array<Bool> = [lastNameTextField.text?.isEmpty, phoneNumberTextField.text?.isEmpty, firstNameTextField.text?.isEmpty]

    if (textfield[0] || textfield [1] || textfield [2])
    {
        print("Textfield is empty")
        continue_Button.isEnabled = false
        continue_Button.alpha = 0.5
    }
    else 
    {
        print("Textfield is full")
        continue_Button.isEnabled = true
        continue_Button.alpha = 1
    }
}
```